# angularjs ng-repeat in a modal with ng-if

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

I have a list of data which i need to show in a modal popup. This modal is done in bootstrap. I have a controller attached to this html. Based on selected type or click i have to open the popup and display data in it in tabular format.

```
<modal  visible="showModal" >
 <div class="table-responsive" >  <!-- <div class="table-responsive" > -->
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover success table-striped table-condensed">
  <thead>
  <tr class="success"  style="table-layout:fixed">
  <th class="alignAll visited" >Country</th>
  <th class="alignAll visited" >Current Date</th>
  <th class="alignAll visited" >Previous Date</th>
  <th class="alignAll visited" >Difference</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
                                <!-- thead Ends ./ -->
<tbody id="tableRowData">
{{dim}}
<tr ng-if="dim==totalRevenue" ng-repeat="disp in allDimensions">
<td class="alignLeft" ><strong>{{disp.country}}</strong></td>
<td class="textCenter" >{{disp.prevDate}}</td>
<td class="textCenter" >{{disp.prevToPrevDate}}</td>
<td class="textCenter" >{{disp.diffRevenue}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="hideModal()" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</modal>
```

and the controller looks like this.

```
app.controller('landingPageController', function($scope,$http,$rootScope,$q)
{

/*Global Variables*/

  //Configure Every Page Aspect From MainController Such as common Calendar Dates

    /*Modal PopUp At RootScope*/

    $rootScope.showModal = false;
    $rootScope.toggleModal = function(val)
    {
        $rootScope.showModal = !$scope.showModal;
        if(val=="revenue")
        {
        $rootScope.dim = "totalRevenue";
        log($rootScope.allDimensions);  
        // Filter Data Based On Selection
        //$scope.filterDim = $.filterByDim($scope.dim,$rootScope.allDimensions);
        //  $.calculateDimensions(dim,$scope.allDimensions);
        }
        else if(val=="cartAban")
        {

            $rootScope.dim  = "cartAbandonment";

        } else if(val=="totalOrders")
        {

            $rootScope.dim = "totalOrders";

        } else if(val=="pageView")
        {

            $rootScope.dim  = "totalPageViews"; 
        }
        else
        {
            log("No Context Found");
        }

    };
    $rootScope.hideModal = function()
    {
        $rootScope.showModal =false;
  }
}
```

I have all $scope.allDimensions which contains all the object.My object looks like this.

```
{"data":[

{
"prevDate":"2015-05-27",
"prevToPrevDate":"2015-05-26",
"diffRevenue":110,
"diffCartAbandonment":-110,
"diffTotalOrders":-110,
"diffPageView":-110,
"country":"UKM",
"prevToPrevRevenue":110,
"prevRevenue":110,
"prevToCartAbandonment":110,
"prevCartAbandonment":110,
"prevToTotalOrders":110,
"prevTotalOrders":110,
"prevToPageView":110,
"prevPageView":110
},

{
    "prevDate":"2015-05-27",
"prevToPrevDate":"2015-05-26",
"diffRevenue":110,
"diffCartAbandonment":-110,
"diffTotalOrders":-110,
"diffPageView":-110,
"country":"UKM",
"prevToPrevRevenue":110,
"prevRevenue":110,
"prevToCartAbandonment":110,
"prevCartAbandonment":110,
"prevToTotalOrders":110,
"prevTotalOrders":110,
"prevToPageView":110,
"prevPageView":110
}]}
```

I am not able to make this work.

Is there any way i can have `ng-repeat` use with `ng-if` and make this scenario work. `ng-if="dim==<some value>` can have any anything and based on that I would populate the table in a modal.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ng-if` you should use a filter (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter) on your `ng-repeat` to exclude certain items from your table.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=disp%20in%20allDimensions.data&p1=object:8&p2=%7B%22prevDate%22:%222015-05-28%22,%22prevToPrevDate%22:%222015-05-27%22,%22diffRevenue%22:-6613,%22diffCartAbandonment%22:19804,%22diffTotalOrders%22:-6651,%22diffPageView%22:92420,%22country%22:%22UNITED%20KINGDOM%22,%22prevToPrevRevenue%22:12783,%22prevRevenue%22:19396,%22prevToCartAbandonment%22:107527,%22prevCartAbandonment%22:87723,%22prevToTotalOrders%22:13256,%22prevTotalOrders%22:19907,%22prevToPageView%22:501792,%22prevPageView%22:409372,%22$$hashKey%22:%22object:8%22%7D

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to have your data displayed then take a look at my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adamjld/z1mybzzc/). This I believe is what you need..

```
<tr ng-repeat="disp in allDimensions.data">
```